# Exibir HTML com o TWIG

Tags: php, html, twig

Estou usando o TWIG em um projeto meu mas não estou conseguindo exibir uma string que tenha o Negrito ou Itálico, ele simplesmente ignora. Já outros comandos HTML são exibidos normalmente.

Exemplo:

```
{{ 'Ao <strong><em><u>contr&aacute;rio do que se acredita</u></em></strong>,<span style="color:#FF0000"> Lorem Ipsum n&atilde;o &eacute; simplesmente um texto rand&ocirc;mico</span>. ' }}
```

Retorno:
Sai o texto todo com o sublinhado e com a font na cor vermelha mas o Negrito e o Itálico nadinha.

Já tentei assim também e nada:

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ 'Ao <strong><em><u>contr&aacute;rio do que se acredita</u></em></strong>,<span style="color:#FF0000"> Lorem Ipsum n&atilde;o &eacute; simplesmente um texto rand&ocirc;mico</span>. ' }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Como está o seu CSS?

Comment: Estava sem nada. Agora que você falou eu criei as tags e tudo certo. Obrigadão

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo Você pode responder sua própria pergunta pra ajudar outros com a mesma dúvida no futuro.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
{% autoescape false %}
    Ao <strong><em><u>contr&aacute;rio do que se acredita...
{% endautoescape %}
```

Ou

```
{{ 'Ao <strong><em><u>contr&aacute;rio do que se acredita...' | raw }}
```